# What is the best way to use async/await inside onAuthStateChanged() of Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, async-await, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase authentication with async/await in React Native. I'm looking for a better way to await inside firebase function. So my question is What is the best way to use async/await inside `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()`?

Now, I implement it in this way. Create a async function inside `onAuthStateChanged()` and call itself. Like the example below... However, I think it looks weird.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  const asyncFunc = async () => {
    await doSomething();
  }

  asyncFunc();
});
```

Is there any better way to implement it?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
  const data = await getData();
  const action = await doSomething();
  // etc.
});


// also you can use
async function asyncHandler(user) {
    const data = await doSomething();
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(asyncHandler);
```

Comment: Oh why i miss that. I used to implement like your first example, but I got an error. so I thought it cannot be implemented in that way. Perhaps  I misunderstood something.

Comment: Kinda late to the party, but does anybody know how to do this using flutter? Can't seem to find a way of calling Firestore after Firebase.auth returns User.

Comment: Hi dteterevkov. Regarding flutter you can do it like this.
Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.asyncMap((FirebaseUser firebaseUser) => _yourAsyncMethod(firebaseUser));
    
  }

The magic is in asyncMap :-) hope this will help you.