# Custom firebase functions in react app not returning value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have made some custom firebase functions for my react app, so I don't have to write the whole code every time. The issue is that when there is a value to return (such as a user JSON), it doesn't return it when I called from another file.

Here is the piece of code not working:

*Functions.js*

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

const AuthState = () => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      return user;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
};

export {AuthState}
```

I call it in my React entry file:
*App.js*

```
import {AuthState} from './Functions'

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const result = AuthState();
    console.log(result) // Undefined
  }
  ...
```

I have tried to use normal functions rather than arrow functions but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged receives a callback. Inside that callback you return the user. I would recommend getting familiar with callbacks and it should be quite easy to find the solution.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583184/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-async-await-inside-onauthstatechanged-of-firebase

Comment: I have just tried, but it isn't working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the firebase methods you're accessing are asynchronous, but your code ignores that and expects them to work synchronously. Essentially, the function will return while waiting for the async actions to resolve.

You call `AuthState`. The operations `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` are fired, waiting for firebase to complete it's tasks and return. Before that happens, the rest of the lines in the function are executed. There are none, so an undefined is returned. Later, the callback passed to onAuthStateChanged is triggered, but is bound to nothing, so the resolved return values are unreachable.

To trigger some code once the operations have actually completed, you can change your code to use an async construct, either callbacks or promises.

callbacks:

```
const AuthState = (cb) => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      cb(user);
    } else {
     cb(null);
    }
  });
};
```

Now, integrating the timing of an async operations with the render methods of React is a but more complicated. Don't put async code like that into the `componentDidMount` property. That can cause infinite update loops. Instead, either initialize in the constructor, or call when the user triggers it (i.e. a button click or pressing enter):

```
import {AuthState} from './Functions'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(super) {
    props(super)
    this.state = {
      result = null
    }
    // get the results of component render initialization:
    AuthState(res => {
      this.setState({
        result: res
      })
      console.log(res)
    });

    // or you can wrap that in a function for attaching to DOM event listeners: 
    this.clickHandler = e => {
      AuthState(res => {
        this.setState({
          result: res
        })
        console.log(res)
      });
    }
  }
  ...
```